# По какому правилу ставится тире?

Tags: пунктуация, тире

По какому правилу разрешается ставить тире в предложении: ***"Возьми, да купи запятые, без этого текст - не текст"***?

Answer (score 1):

Корректная запись: ***Возьми да купи запятые, без этого текст не текст.***

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1. Глагольная частица ***возьми да*** входит в состав  осложненного простого глагольного сказуемого, например:  А он взял и уехал. Вот возьму и уйду.
2. Запятая при повторяющихся словах  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=104#pp104 пункт 4.

Запятая не ставится:

...между двумя **повторяющимися** словами, из которых второе употреблено с отрицанием не, если сочетание этих слов образует **смысловое целое,** выражающее неполное отрицание или неопределенность в обозначении чего-либо:  На нём надето что-то круглое: сюртук не сюртук, пальто не пальто, фрак не фрак, а что-то среднее (С. Щ.);

Comment: Шарон, здравствуйте! Как там мой вопрос? Что думаете про него?

Comment: Артем, здравствуйте!   Сейчас я оглядываюсь вокруг и думаю: "Какой же вопрос Артем имеет в виду?"  Вы не могли бы дать ссылку?

Comment: :)) Про [время с пол-](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/468295/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be?r=SearchResults&s=1|69.8804).

Comment: Артем, это надо подумать, там у вас целый диспут состоялся. Чуть позже, по возможности, ОК?

Comment: Что-то не помню диспута.)) Конечно, как сможете, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Это тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, которые выражены существительными. При этом при отрицании во второй части тире обычно не ставится, но если присутствует противопоставление, то тире нужно. В вашем примере противопоставление очевидно и акцентировано.

Comment: А что за противопоставление? У Розенталя об этом не сказано.

Comment: У Лопатина: Тире между подлежащим и именным сказуемым не ставится, если при сказуемом-существительном имеется отрицание: Пейзаж не довесок к прозе и не украшение (Пауст.); Россия  не Петербург, она огромная (Пришв.); Старость  не радость (посл.).

Однако при противопоставлении сказуемое с отрицанием требует постановки тире (не… а): И в то же время замечал, что он — не господин в своем доме, а лишь составная часть его (М. Г.) (ср. без противопоставления: Он не господин в своем доме ).

Comment: В примере Горького необходимость тире ощущается. Противопоставление — это когда есть "не... а", а здесь нет.