# "Полпервого" или "в полпервого"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

У Лопатина приводятся примеры с предлогом (§ 136 п. 5 прим.): ***в** полпервого (встретиться), **в** пол-одиннадцатого (прийти).*

Тем не менее вроде бы привычны сочетания типа *приходи полпервого, собираемся полседьмого.*

***Так когда всё-таки нужен предлог, а когда нет?***

Comment: Вообще не слышал такого.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Пыф! Знаю, как правильно, но пока не могу сформулировать. Подумаю. Озадачил, Артём.

Comment: Серьезный вопрос. Странно, что он замалчивается в лингвистике, учитывая популярность похожих выражений и скорее всего, довольно давнюю историю. Интересно, когда это начало входить в обиход?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смысл ситуации мне понятен.

1. В нейтральной речи мы обычно используем предлог В, что видно и в художественных текстах:

Винительный падеж: *Отец Власий обыкновенно начинает прием **в полпятого** утра ровно.*

Именительный падеж. *Было уже **полпятого**.*

2. Сравним два варианта.

(1) *Сейчас пять часов. Встретимся в семь часов*. Мы не можем пропустить предлог, иначе будет явное нарушение грамматики.

(2) *Сейчас полпятого. Встретимся в полседьмого.* А можно и так: *Встретимся полседьмого.*

Здесь грамматическая вольность практически незаметна, поэтому в разговорном варианте она сначала допускается, а потом и закрепляется в разговорной речи. Вариант ненормированный, но довольно частотный.

Это обычное явление в языке: мы заботимся о правильной сочетаемости "на слух", то есть  при непосредственном контакте слов. И допускаем отклонение в других случаях.

Или такое объяснение: ― *Встретимся полседьмого. ― Почему вы пропускаете предлог, это же В. падеж? ―  А я имею в виду: когда на часах будет полседьмого, а это уже И. падеж.*

3. А вот пример В. падежа без предлога из художественной литературы:

*Иногда среди ночи, чаще всего **полпятого утра**, просыпался в холодном поту.* [Василий Аксенов. Таинственная страсть (2007)]

Comment: Спасибо большое, Шарон!

Answer (score 1):

Встретились, пришли, вернулись, улетели (когда? во сколько? в какое время?) — в пять часов, в восемь вечера, в три, в десять минут четвёртого, в полпервого, в полдесятого.
Это винительный падеж с предлогом "в".

**В двенадцать пятнадцать** меня охватила ярость, **в полпервого** я страшно взволновалась... [Дина Рубина. Наш китайский бизнес // «Знамя», 1999]
Патрульные на путях заметили их и спросили издалека, куда это они собрались **в полвторого** ночи... [Дмитрий Глуховский. Метро 2033 (2005)]
Прихожу **в пол-одиннадцатого** ― занимаюсь с час и спать. [В. А. Чивилихин. Дневники, письма (1948)]

Вполне возможно, что беспредложное употребление связано с тем, что "часовые показания" с *пол-* **неизменяемы** (полвторого, полтретьего... полдвенадцатого), а вопросительное слово "сколько" в винительном падеже имеет ту же форму.

Comment: И что, беспредложное всегда неверное?

Comment: Ну почему ж всегда? Я подошел к окну ― прямо напротив гостиницы помещалась ратуша, огромные башенные часы показывали полпятого... [Марина Дяченко, Сергей Дяченко. Привратник (1994)]  Часы показывали половину восьмого. [Борис Левин. Инородное тело (1965-1994)]

Comment: Насчет неизменяемости: Он пришел половина второго. Все звучит и типа изменяемо.

Comment: Вы путаете: *наше* слово (полпятого, полседьмого, пол-одиннадцатого) не изменяется никак. А сочетание *половина чего-то*, конечно, склоняется, но только первое слово.

Comment: Ну не создавать же отдельный вопрос про словосочетания: половина пятого, половина седьмого, ...

Comment: Нет, Рим, я спрашивал про случаи, когда предлог в принципе возможен, а не про такие, как у тебя.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, разгадку надо искать в отличии предложений

```
Он пришел без десяти двенадцать.

Он пришел в без десяти двенадцать.
```

Comment: В случае с "без" предлог "в" опускается, а в случае с "пол" — нет (по крайней мере, не сталкивался).

Comment: Есть такое дело, встречается. Полвторого ночи я постучал в дверь квартиры№ 29 первого дома. [Андрей Раскин, Юлия Шуляк. Где вино и женщины? // «Русский репортер», 2014] ― Ну хорошо, хорошо, Юра! Не обижайся только. Полпервого я буду дома. Жду тебя. [В. М. Шапко. Синдром веселья Плуготаренко // «Волга», 2016]